# Keyword Box Form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, forms

I want to make keyword box like this, and is Richtextbox able to do it?

[image: Keyword Box]

I only need to enter a keyword that ends with a comma, then it will automatically become a keyword box like that

I could ask ChatGPT, but it's too popular right now too much traffic and I can't enter it now

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty here is how this label should be implemented. It is recommended that you use custom tags.
Let's split the control first. The whole control can be regarded as a selected label interface.
There are many small tabs in the selected tab interface, which are composed of one by one.

**One: We focus on implementing the label control in the selected label interface**

1. The label control can inherit UserControl and then add a label control to the UserControl interface to simulate the close button.

   ```
   public partial class TagControl : BaseRadiusUserControl
   ```
2. Then write a defined close event

   ```
   [Description("Close Event "), Category("Customize ")]
            public event EventHandler CloseClick;
   ```
3. Click X on the label control to trigger the close event

   ```
   private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseClick?.Invoke(this,e);

        }
   ```
4. Then write an assignment method to adjust the size of the control when the text value is greater than 2.

   ```
   public void SetText(string text)
        {
            this.Content = text;
            if (text.Length > 1)
            {
                this.Width = 60 + (text.Length - 1) * 20;
            }
        }
   ```

In this way, the small label control is realized!

**Two: The selected tab interface uses the flowlaoutpanel control**